# Need Solution : Message is not Showing Toast

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity

My Current Code is Like This...And Problem is just I Am Not Able to show message in Toast....

Can anyone help me with it as which method or Context i needed to use here ?

I am Successfully connected to the server but the response is coming on console but not able to show it in toast message.

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Socket client;
Context c;
String userInput;
TextView txtV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    txtV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    MyConnection sendMessageTask = new MyConnection();
    sendMessageTask.execute();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

private class MyConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String userInput;
    Context c1;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            client = new Socket("10.10.0.122", 1978); // connect to the server
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            while (true)
            {
                userInput = stdIn.readLine();
                System.out.println(userInput);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(c,userInput,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't mix multiple `Writers` and `OutputStreams` or `Readers` and `InputStreams` on the same socket. It won't work.
2. `PrintWriter` is buffered. If you write something and then expect a response you need to flush it after the write.

Comment: CAN U GIVE ME A SAMPLE CODE ?

Comment: Why This is not Showing in Toast @EJP